How to fix this keystroke script in a hidden window?
I'm trying to make it so that when the program starts, key is pressed in a hidden game window.
import win32gui, win32process, win32con, win32api
import time

# VK vars

VK_KEY_W = 0x57
VK_KEY_A = 0x41
VK_KEY_S = 0x53
VK_KEY_D = 0x44

def find_window_by_name(window_name):
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
if hwnd == 0:
raise Exception(f"Window with name '{window_name}' not found.")
print(hwnd)
return hwnd

def send_key_to_window(hwnd, key, sleep):
time.sleep(sleep)
win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN, key, 0)
time.sleep(sleep)
win32api.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_KEYUP, key, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
window_name = "Roblox"
hwnd = find_window_by_name(window_name)
send_key_to_window(hwnd, VK_KEY_W, 1) # Test key press

the program finds the hwnd of the game, does not give errors, but nothing happens. I thought I would find the answer on my own, and I’ve been trying to solve this problem for two weeks now, but since I can’t make any progress, I decided to write my problem here, sorry.

always put code with correct indentations because sometimes this can be main problem.

sometimes games can use own methods to get key events (instead of using system functions) and this can make problem. I don't use Windows and I don't know other module which can work with games.
